# Get nearest GPS Points from MySQL

Tags: mysql, geolocation

I have a table with  `float latitude` and `float longitude` (like `47.960237,13.796564`).

Now i want to select roughly points that are about 2km around a specific point.

How do i do that fast and with less cpu usage?

**UPDATE**

Maybe i have wrong expressed my problem. Is there a direct method to use a BETWEEN and direct coordinates like  x between 47.95 and 47.94 and y between 13.78 and 13.76 (according to my example point)

Comment: http://www.techfounder.net/2009/02/02/selecting-closest-values-in-mysql/

Comment: i need something about gps points, sorry

Comment: GPS points or numbers? What's the difference?

Comment: @WouterJ - Difference is dimensionality. Number example given above is a single dimension. Solution to the problem is multidimensional, which is why the Haversine Distance formula gives you the distance between two pairs of points on a sphere (the Earth in this case).

Answer (score 2):

You should change your table to use points

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/de/point-property-functions.html

With the help of those, you may use this query

```
SELECT *,3956 * 2 * ASIN(SQRT( POWER(SIN((@orig_lat -abs( dest.lat)) * pi()/180 / 2),2) + COS(@orig_lat * pi()/180 ) * COS( abs (dest.lat) *  pi()/180) * POWER(SIN((@orig_lon – dest.lon) *  pi()/180 / 2), 2) )) as distanceFROM TABLE desthaving distance < @distORDER BY distance limit 10
```

Comment: as described here http://www.scribd.com/doc/2569355/Geo-Distance-Search-with-MySQL

Comment: I'm not sure why the answers aren't more clear, but the algorithm you're looking for is the Haversine-Distance. Gut says most of these answers came from Google's solid example found here: https://developers.google.com/maps/solutions/store-locator/clothing-store-locator

Answer (score 1):

Try this query

```
SELECT ((ACOS(SIN($lat * PI() / 180) * SIN(lat * PI() / 180) + COS($lat * PI() / 180)
* COS(lat * PI() / 180) * COS(($lon – lon) * PI() / 180)) * 180 / PI()) * 60 * 1.1515) AS `distance` 
FROM `members` 
HAVING `distance`<=’10′ ORDER BY `distance` ASC
```

Comment: this will be slow as no indexes can be used

Answer (score 0):

MySQL seem to have [spatial extensions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/spatial-extensions.html), I have never used MySql, but if these are anything like the spatial extensions SqlServer then they will have the functions you need including the use of **fast** spatial indexes.

Based on a quick read of the MySQL docs, store the data as [points](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/gis-class-point.html), then use the [MBRContains](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/functions-for-testing-spatial-relations-between-geometric-objects.html#function_mbrcontains)(g1,g2) function, add a [SPATIAL indexes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/optimizing-spatial-analysis.html) however I think only MyISAM surports spatial indexes.

Hopefull there is a MySQL function to find the nearest pointk, if not feed all the close points into a 2nd query that uses trig (as per other answers) to find the bast point.

Comment: Please correct me if I am wrong, but `MBRContains(g1, g2)` is used with `polygon and multyPolygon` data, not with points.